# Absolute div and text at bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a div with absolute position and some text into it. I want to place the text at bottom. I have done this with:

```
display: table-cell;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: bottom;
```

but it works only if i remove `position:absolute`. I need absolute position (`overflow:auto` works with position absolute).
Div content is dynamic, I don't have a fixed number of lines so I need both overflow function and text align at bottom.
Thanks for your support

```css
#mydiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1%;
  bottom: 1%;
  left: 2%;
  width: 40vw;
  height: 49vh;
  max-width: 260px;
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: auto;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div id="mydiv">
  <p>line1</p>
  <p>line2</p>
  <p>line3</p>

</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to display `p` as columns or in one row?

Comment: i want display p as columns

Comment: I use overflow:auto for this reason but I need "bottom floating" it works if you remove absolute position...why? maybe I should use :after ?

Comment: So this is like some chat box or news feed box?

Comment: yes. I woluld achieve a "printing effect", insert text from bottom to the top and when the box is full, overflow